# Power Series with singularities in {z: |z|=1}

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, singularity-theory

> Prove that all the points in $D=\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \mid z\mid=1 \right\}$ are singularities of the function
>   $$
> f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n!}}{n!}
> $$

This was easy for the function $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}$, since I used that for $z \in E=\left\{ e^{2\pi i \cdot a/b} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$, $g(z)$ diverges, and then the assumption follows because $\overline{E}=D$. But I can not use that with $\ f$ because of the $1/n!$ factor. How can I improve the same argument to make it work with $\ f$?

Comment: Is this true? The series is a sub-series of $e^z$ which has no finite singularities.

Comment: Well it must be true, the series in $f$ has convergence radius $R=1$, this means in $D$ there must be at least a singularity isn't it? 
However it is clear that $f(1)=e \neq \infty$, but that doses not necessary means that $1$ is not a singularity.

Comment: @martycohen It's a subseries of $1/(1-z)$.

Comment: Actually, I think we are both wrong - it's a subseries of $-\ln(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n/n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $1+ zf'(z) = g(z)$, so $f$ and $g$ have the same singularities.

Comment: Nice answer @LukasGeyer. And how we explain that $f(1)\neq \infty$ even if $1$ is a singularity of $f$ ? this makes a lot of noise in my head, I always thought singularities as points where the function is not well defined.

Comment: I think the answer to my previous comment may be that even that $f(1)\neq\infty$ we have that $f$ is not analytic in $1$, so indeed $1$ is a singularity of $f$.

Comment: Yes, singularities are those points where the function does not have an analytic continuation into a neighborhood, which means you can have continuous extensions to parts of the boundary but still have singularities there.